# Create a PFX File from GoDaddy Issued Private Key and Wildcard Certificate

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, private-key, pem, pfx

I recently purchased a wildcard SSL certificate from GoDaddy and I need to convert it to a `pfx` file.

First, GoDaddy gave me two text blobs in their web UI, a CSR and Private Key:

CSR:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
MIICWDCCAUICAQAwFzEVMBMGA1UEAwwMKi5jeW50aGlhLmlvMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG
9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAzcxAT8EtKxb4BSCRYBYcTDt8DgR/Fe/rjBpl
...
```

Private Key:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEvQIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKcwggSjAgEAAoIBAQDNzEBPwS0rFvgF
IJFgFhxMO3wOBH8V7+uMGmXDx+n3Mzvz9gk0nj/h5kX9RH+M9byS4iCfUZ8rURXQ
...
```

Next, I downloaded a Zip file containing two `crt` files and a `pem` file:

```
54994fbd90cc1fc8.crt
54994fbd90cc1fc8.pem
gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt
```

54994fbd90cc1fc8.crt

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIGiDCCBXCgAwIBAgIIVJlPvZDMH8gwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQAwgbQxCzAJBgNV
BAYTAlVTMRAwDgYDVQQIEwdBcml6b25hMRMwEQYDVQQHEwpTY290dHNkYWxlMRow
...
```

54994fbd90cc1fc8.pem

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIGiDCCBXCgAwIBAgIIVJlPvZDMH8gwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQAwgbQxCzAJBgNV
BAYTAlVTMRAwDgYDVQQIEwdBcml6b25hMRMwEQYDVQQHEwpTY290dHNkYWxlMRow
...
```

gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- 
MIIE0DCCA7igAwIBAgIBBzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADCBgzELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMx
EDAOBgNVBAgTB0FyaXpvbmExEzARBgNVBAcTClNjb3R0c2RhbGUxGjAYBgNVBAoT
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIEfTCCA2WgAwIBAgIDG+cVMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAMGMxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVT
MSEwHwYDVQQKExhUaGUgR28gRGFkZHkgR3JvdXAsIEluYy4xMTAvBgNVBAsTKEdv
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIEADCCAuigAwIBAgIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADBjMQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzEh 
MB8GA1UEChMYVGhlIEdvIERhZGR5IEdyb3VwLCBJbmMuMTEwLwYDVQQLEyhHbyBE
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

I need to generate a `pfx` file for my cloud provider.

I tried this command:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out cert.pfx -inkey generated-private-key.txt -in 54994fbd90cc1fc8.pem
```

But I got this error:

```
unable to load private key
4530953728:error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start 
line:crypto/pem/pem_lib.c:745:Expecting: ANY PRIVATE KEY
```

The file `generated-private-key.txt` has `400`. permissions:

```
-r--------@ 1 david  staff  1707 Oct 24 20:12 generated-private-key.txt
```

How do I generate a `pfx` file from the files I have? Should I generate my own private key with `ssh-keygen` and then re-key with a new CSR in the GoDaddy UI?

Answer (score 2):

This turned out to be because the key was in UTF8-BOM instead of UTF8 format.

Comment: dos2unix path_to_file_in_bom ||||

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/381230/how-can-i-remove-the-bom-from-a-utf-8-file

Answer (score 0):

I used this command from [Unix SOF answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/381230/how-can-i-remove-the-bom-from-a-utf-8-file?newreg=725300f8630548a59f7edb2c56cada16):

`sed '1s/^\xEF\xBB\xBF//' < orig.txt > new.txt`